# How to improve performance of connect/introspect call (IdentityServer4)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 for token generation and during the token validation using "connect/introspect" - it consumes more than 600 ms. But I need to improve this response time. When I debugged the code found that `FindApiResourceAsync` and `FindClientByIdAsync` methods are called internally. Do we need these calls during introspect?

I have couple of questions.

**Question 1:**

In my solution, EntityFramework is used and in that using DI Client and ResourceStore values are declared as below.

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IClientStore, ClientStore>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IResourceStore, ResourceStore>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICorsPolicyService, CorsPolicyService>();
```

Due to this above code, `FindApiResourceAsync` and `FindClientByIdAsync` methods are called during "connect/introspect" call? For the token validation using "introspect" do we really need to verify the Client and Resource values? Is it not enough to only check `PersistedGrants` values?

**Question 2:**

In the `FindClientByIdAsync` method, I am using "Include" for loading the dependent entities of Client. Does it impact performance? If it is so, what is alternate approach to add the dependent entities of Client?

```
   var client = _context.Clients.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.ClientGrantTypes)
            .Include(x => x.ClientRedirectUris)
            .Include(x => x.ClientPostLogoutRedirectUris)
            .Include(x => x.ClientScopes)
            .Include(x => x.ClientSecrets)
            .Include(x => x.ClientClaims)   
            .Include(x => x.ClientIdPrestrictions)
            .Include(x => x.ClientCorsOrigins)
            .Include(x => x.ClientProperties)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == clientId);
```

Comment: did you post this question on https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4?